# Can I use Grub only for windows 7?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I installed Ubuntu and now I want to get rid of it because I hardly use it. I deleted the Ubuntu partitions, but that also broke Grub. I reinstalled Ubuntu and then repaired Grub, but I still want to get rid of Ubuntu. I don't have a CD burner, so I cant create a Windows rescue disk. I want to know if I can delete Ubuntu partitions and reinstall Grub via live USB to still be able to boot into Windows 7.

Comment: @searchfgold6789 remember that he wants to keep GRUB, and can't get a windows reparation disk.

Comment: @Angel Can you [edit] your question and provide the output of `cat /etc/fstab/` and `fdisk -l`

Comment: There are options on the duplicate that can be run from a LiveUSB version of Ubuntu (that preserve GRUB). I think the cleaner solution is getting access to a Windows recovery CD but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the partitions, and then try [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair): That will repair Grub and not install Ubuntu.

Comment: I think he'll need at least a partition for Grub files (i.e. `/boot`) as I doubt that Grub supports NTFS.